# Windows batch command question, start excel temp.xls

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wanted to know that if I do

```
start excel temp.xls
```

The os will start a new excel instance and open the workbook temp.xls in that instance, AS AN ATOMIC action.

Right now what I have is

```
start excel
start temp.xls
```

And most often these two command will mess up my other excel instance, ie, opening temp.xls in another excel instance that has another workbook already opened.

Thanks,

Comment: @Cody Gray: I tried it several times. Seems fine. But my environment is different from the real one, which has many heavy duty spreadsheet running.

Comment: To guarantee a new instance, you could use VBA and CreateObject to start Excel.  The COM object has a method to open files as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I **think** that "start excel temp.xls" will open temp.xls in the Excel instance started by start, you'd be on the safe side, if you use

```
  "<PathToExcel>excel" [/<opt>] "<PathToXls>temp.xls"
```

For opt see [cli for excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/command-line-switches-for-excel-HA010158030.aspx) (pick the docs for your version).

Answer (score 1):

The [Command-line switches for Excel 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/command-line-switches-for-excel-HA010158030.aspx?CTT=1) document explains the *switches*:

> You can change certain aspects of how
>   the program starts by adding
>   subcommands called switches to the
>   Excel.exe command. A switch appears as
>   a space after the main command,
>   followed by a slash mark (/) and the
>   name of the switch. The switch is
>   sometimes followed by another space
>   and then one or more specific
>   instructions called parameters, which
>   give the program further information
>   about how to execute the Excel.exe
>   command.

In your case you do not use a switch but a *parameter*. It is used to *give the program further information about how to execute the Excel.exe command*.

**Parameter**: file name
**Description**: *starts* Excel *and opens* the specified file.

So I would assume that the parameter is bound to the excel instance started.