# Start Excel file from Windows batch script in safemode, use default file association

Tags: excel, windows, batch-file

**Question Summary:**
Can I start Excel file Installer.xlsm from Windows batch script in *safemode*, without providing EXCEL.EXE installation path?

**Details**

I have a windows batch script which downloads the latest versions of a family of Excel Add-ins from a remote server, places them in a directory (C:\appname\AddIns) and calls the Excel file Installer.xlsm.

Upon loading, Installer.xlsm executes a VBA macro, which uninstalls older versions of the add-ins and installs their newer version.

Currently I start Installer.xlsm using the command:

```
start "Launching installer file" /wait "<Path to file>\Installer.xlsm"
```

What's great about it is that it uses Windows' file association to open Excel, and I don't have to provide the EXCEL.EXE installation path (multiple users with different machine images and MS Office versions).

Now I'd like to load Installer.xlsm in *safemode*, to make sure that no add-ins are loaded and no other code is run while Installer.xlsm tries to work with the add-ins.

I know I can use `"<PathToExcel>excel" /safemode "<PathToXls>Installer.xlsm"` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5803704/3233629), but this method doesn't use Windows' file association and requires that I provide a path.

We have users with various machine images, using different versions of MS Office, so I do not want to get into hardcoding all possible Excel installation locations.

Can I do something of the following form:

```
start "Launching installer file" /wait "<Path to file>\Installer.xlsm /safemode"
```

I tried different possible combinations without success. How would you do it?

Comment: Why is directly using the excel executable an issue?

Comment: Hi @Compo See my question. It requires providing the path to the installation location of EXCEL.exe, which will be different for users of different machine images and MS Office versions. I'm not aware of an env variable that points to MS office installation folder, and don't want to hardcode possible locations, only to discover occasionally that there's a new possibility which has to be added to the script. Do you know of a different way of obtaining EXCEL.exe path dynamically?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/280176/how-to-run-ms-excel-2007-from-a-batch-file

Comment: @Tamara, the location of the installed excel executable regardless of recent version or OS is easily retrieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I suggest to read the Microsoft documentation page [Application Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration). It explains how the installer of an application or an application suite like Microsoft Office should register the installed application(s) so that the executable(s) of the application(s) can be found by other applications.

Recommended is creating under registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

a subkey with name of the executable file like `excel.exe` with default string value being name of the executable with full path and **optionally** adding one more string value with name `Path` containing just the path to the executable. The `Path` string can but most not exist and it can but must not end with a backslash.

The command **START** uses also this key to find an application as explained in answer on [Where is “START” searching for executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386403/3074564)

The installers of the various versions of Microsoft Office register `excel.exe` key under this key too.

So the easiest method on Windows Vista and later Windows versions to get installation location of Microsoft Excel is:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=1 tokens=2*" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\excel.exe" /ve 2^>nul') do set "ExcelApp=%%~B"
echo ExcelApp=%ExcelApp%
pause
```

But on Windows XP the output of `reg.exe` is different and requires for that reason this batch code:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=3 tokens=3*" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\excel.exe" /ve 2^>nul') do set "ExcelApp=%%~B"
echo ExcelApp=%ExcelApp%
pause
```

The different outputs are explained in answer on [Read words separated by space & string value also contains space in a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39409862/3074564) in batch code written to get string value of a default string of a registry key containing spaces.

And it is good coding practice to add extra code which handles an error case like registry key does not exist at all because Microsoft Excel is not installed at all.

But is it possible with batch code to do what command **START** respectively the Windows shell function [ShellExecuteEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexa) does on using in a command prompt window the command line?

```
start "Launching installer file" "C:\Path to file\Installer.xlsm"
```

Yes, it is possible as the commented batch code below demonstrates.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem First query default string value of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlsm from registry.
call :GetDefaultRegValue "HKCR\.xlsm"

rem Is there no key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlsm or was the default string empty?
if not defined RegValue goto GetFromAppPaths

SET RegValue
rem Get the shell command line used for opening a *.xlsm file.
call :GetDefaultRegValue "HKCR\%RegValue%\shell\open\command"

rem Could the command line not read successfully from Windows registry?
if not defined RegValue goto GetFromAppPaths

SET RegValue
rem The command line contains as first string usually enclosed in double
rem quotes EXCEL.EXE with full path enclosed in double quotes. And there
rem can be even more arguments on the command line which are not needed
rem here. The command line below is used to get just first string of
rem the command line which should be EXCEL.EXE with full path.
for %%I in (%RegValue%) do set "RegValue=%%~I" & goto CheckExcelExistence

rem It is not good when both registry queries above fail. This means
rem either Microsoft Excel is not installed at all or a version of
rem Excel is installed which does not support *.xlsm files like Excel
rem of MS Office 2003, MS Office 2000 or MS Office 97.

rem However, perhaps just *.xlsm is not correct registered and therefore
rem get full path to excel.exe from application registration key.

:GetFromAppPaths
call :GetDefaultRegValue "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\excel.exe"
if defined RegValue goto CheckExcelExistence

echo Failed to determine installation location of Microsoft Excel.
echo/
endlocal
pause
goto :EOF

:CheckExcelExistence
SET RegValue
rem Remove surrounding double quotes if the Excel executable file name
rem read from Windows registry is still enclosed in double quotes.
set "RegValue=%RegValue:"=%"
if exist "%RegValue%" goto :RunInstall

echo Registered "%RegValue%" does not exist.
echo/
endlocal
pause
goto :EOF

:RunInstall
SET RegValue
ECHO start "Launching installer file" /wait "%RegValue%" "%~dp0Installer.xlsm" /safemode
endlocal
goto :EOF


rem This subroutine queries from Windows registry the default string value of
rem the key passed to the subroutine as first and only parameter and assigns
rem this value to environment variable RegValue. Environment variable RegValue
rem is deleted and therefore is not defined after subroutine exits on failure
rem to get the registry value or when the default value is an empty string.
rem This subroutine works for Windows XP and all later versions of Windows.

:GetDefaultRegValue
set "TypeToken=2"

:Reg3Run
for /F "skip=1 tokens=%TypeToken%*" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "%~1" /ve 2^>nul') do (
    if "%%A" == "REG_SZ" (
        if not "%%~B" == "" (
            set "RegValue=%%B"
            goto :EOF
        )
    ) else if "%%A" == "NAME>" (
        set "TypeToken=3"
        goto Reg3Run
    )
)
set "RegValue="
goto :EOF
```

This batch code is just a demonstration. It does not start Excel when really found. Instead it just outputs the command line which would start Excel because of **ECHO** left of `start` ... in block below label `RunInstall`.

Further this batch code contains 4 lines with just `SET RegValue`. Those 4 lines output just the string value queried successfully from Windows registry and stored in environment variable `RegValue`. Those 4 commands help to understand what happens on execution of the batch file. Those four command lines should be deleted finally from batch file and also the single **ECHO** written in upper case.

**Note:** It is quite easy to test what happens if an expected registry key does not exist or its default value is an empty string. Just insert a single character like `#` before last double quote on a line starting with `call :GetDefaultRegValue` and the modified registry key is not found anymore.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `rem /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `reg.exe` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the mind blowing answer! A lot to process here. Beginning experimentation...

Comment: This solution worked great as a method to fetch EXCEL.EXE path dynamically.